# I need to help about " Action Script 3 , public Function with Button " 

Tags: actionscript-3

```
Public function PencereyiGizle ( btn:Button )

{
....
....
}
```

I have a problem with the `btn:Button`

> 1046: Type was not found or was not a
>   compile-time constant:Button..

---

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.NativeWindow;
    import flash.display.NativeWindowInitOptions;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.display.SimpleButton;


    public class PencereyiGizle extends MovieClip
    {
        public var natWindow:NativeWindow=new NativeWindow(
        new NativeWindowInitOptions());
        public var pencereyiAc_Btn:Button;

        public function PencereyiGizle(fro:Button)
        {
            pencereAc_Btn = fro;
            //Pencere ekleniyor
            natWindow.width = 500;
            natWindow.height = 400;
            natWindow.activate();
            natWindow.addEventListener(Event.CLOSING,pencereyiSakla);
            pencereyiAc_Btn.label = "Pencereyi Ac";
            pencereyiAc_Btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,pencereyiAktifEt);
        }
        //pencerenin kapanmasını engelleyip pencereyi gizliyoruz.;
        private function pencereyiSakla(e:Event):void
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            natWindow.visible = false;
        }

        //gizlenen pencereyi tekrar aktif hale getiriyoruz
        private function pencereyiAktifEt(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            natWindow.activate();
        }
    }

}

N AIR;

import PencereyiGizle;

var firat:PencereyiGizle= new PencereyiGizle();
addChild(firat);
```

and then, i get that problem "1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant:Button. "

I have a problem with the btn:Button

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `import` statement to import "Button"

Depending on your requirements it could either be

1. [Spark Button](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/Button.html)

   import spark.components.Button;
2. [MX Button](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/Button.html)

   import mx.controls.Button

**UPDATE**: Looks like [this page](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/414756) has an answer to your question. Specifically check [THIS](http://forums.adobe.com/message/1870229#1870229) answer

Comment: i used that; import fl.controls.Button;

Comment: Are you using Flex or Flash? :S

Answer (score 0):

you problem is your class PencereyiGizle is looking for a button to be passed as a reference in the constructor which you are not doing

```
var firat:PencereyiGizle= new PencereyiGizle();
addChild(firat);
```

you need to pass either an instance name of a button

```
var firat:PencereyiGizle= new PencereyiGizle( someButton );
addChild(firat);
```

or create a new button and pass it along

```
var someButton:Button = new button
var firat:PencereyiGizle= new PencereyiGizle( someButton );
addChild(firat);
```