# 1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant:Button

Tags: actionscript-3

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.NativeWindow;
    import flash.display.NativeWindowInitOptions;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.display.SimpleButton;


    public class PencereyiGizle extends MovieClip
    {
        public var natWindow:NativeWindow=new NativeWindow(
        new NativeWindowInitOptions());
        public var pencereyiAc_Btn:Button;

        public function PencereyiGizle(fro:Button)
        {
            pencereAc_Btn = fro;
            //Pencere ekleniyor
            natWindow.width = 500;
            natWindow.height = 400;
            natWindow.activate();
            natWindow.addEventListener(Event.CLOSING,pencereyiSakla);
            pencereyiAc_Btn.label = "Pencereyi Ac";
            pencereyiAc_Btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,pencereyiAktifEt);
        }
        //pencerenin kapanmasını engelleyip pencereyi gizliyoruz.;
        private function pencereyiSakla(e:Event):void
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            natWindow.visible = false;
        }

        //gizlenen pencereyi tekrar aktif hale getiriyoruz
        private function pencereyiAktifEt(e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            natWindow.activate();
        }
    }


}
```

IN AIR;

```
import PencereyiGizle;

var firat:PencereyiGizle= new PencereyiGizle();
addChild(firat);
```

and then, i get that problem "1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant:Button. "

Comment: possible duplicate of [I need to help about " Action Script 3 , public Function with Button " ...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5766913/i-need-to-help-about-action-script-3-public-function-with-button)

Comment: If you have more information, update your previous question instead of posting a new one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5766913/i-need-to-help-about-action-script-3-public-function-with-button

Answer (score 3):

Based on what is in your imports, I think you want to use the SimpleButton class and not the Button class. (Which is a flash component)

Either that or you are missing this import

```
import fl.controls.Button;
```

Here is an artilce from adobe on the button component.
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/quickstart/button_component_as3.html